# How will a native speaker of American English say this sentence? Will "comma' be replaced with "and" in spoken American English?

Tags: speech

Best Buy plans to reopen its stores on Monday in states that have loosened restrictions, joining a handful of other retailers that are limping back to life after the corona virus forced them to close.

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Are you asking if native English speakers say punctuation out loud? Why would anyone say 'and' where the comma is? Voting to close.

Comment: The comma would not be 'replaced' with anything other than, possibly, a pause, when that sentence is read aloud.

Comment: Its pretty uncommon to hear participle in spoken English. Are you saying you would pause and just say the sentence after comma?

Comment: ssrivas, are you asking how an American would say this in a casual or formal conversation?

Comment: The awkward part of it is "in states that have loosened restrictions".  Normally that phrase would be moved ahead of "Best Buy plans".

Comment: Formal conversation such as an interview or speech or press briefing.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you. How would you say the last bit "joining a handful of other retailers ...'?

Comment: @ssrivas “When reading a sentence one only reads the words that are there, in the order that they are written.”   If you are asking how a native speaker might convey the ideas represented by that sentence in normal everyday conversation, then that becomes primarily opinion based as there are *many* different ways that could be done.

Comment: @Jim. Yes I am asking how a native speaker might convey the ideas in the sentence in casual conversation.

Comment: @ssrivas - There are too many ways they might do that, making this this question not a good fit for ELU.  But I would say that most of those ways would involve using more than one sentence to do it and would likely omit some of the information: “I read that Best Buy is gonna be open again on Monday. At least in some states. So are some other places.  I wonder how much business are they’re really gonna get.”

Answer (score 1):

If you replace the comma with "and", it becomes grammatically incorrect because we would essentially be saying "Best Buy plans...and joining..." where both verbs are different forms. The comma is necessary.

Comment: Perhaps the OP has in mind “…and join…”, which would be lamentable (because it takes away the sense that BB joins *by* reopening) but grammatical.

Comment: @Anton Sherwood Yes, that's exactly what I had in mind. I would really appreciate if you could explain as to why the two clauses can not be joined by AND. I agree with you that BB will join a handful of retailers by reopening but don't understand why using AND will detract from the original intent.

Comment: *and* would allow the reader to understand that reopening and joining are two unrelated actions.

Comment: @Anton Sherwood Thanks, much appreciated.